# Downloading a file using C#

Tags: c#

I have some code to download a text file from a website. When the requested file does not exist, my application downloads a text file which has html content. I need to filter this html content (should not download a text file with html content if the requested file does not exist) and need to download only text files which has the correct content. Below is my code.

```
string FilePath = @"C:\TextFiles\" + FileName + String.Format("{0:00000}", i) + ".TXT";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath));
//MessageBox.Show(FilePath);

using (FileStream download = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    Stream stream = clientx.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
    {

        download.Write(buffer, 0, read);

    }
}
```

Please advice

Comment: If the file is not found, do you need to display a html page instead?

Comment: no, html page should not download.  actually its not a html page. text file with html content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `clientx` is `HttpWebRequest` then just check the StatusCode of the response:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)clientx.GetResponse();
if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error reading page: " + response.StatusCode);
}
else
{
    string FilePath = @"C:\TextFiles\" + FileName + String.Format("{0:00000}", i) + ".TXT";
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath));
    //MessageBox.Show(FilePath);
    using (FileStream download = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        Stream stream = response .GetResponseStream();
        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            download.Write(buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes HttpWebRequest :   when i use HttpWebResponse response = clientx.GetResponse() im having a error message     : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.WebResponse' to 'System.Net.HttpWebResponse'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: See my edit, try having `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)clientx.GetResponse();`

Comment: yes; but still downloading a file with html content.  In the website there are some text files which has some songs. when the requestd file is exist it get downloaded, when not exist application downloads a text file with html content of the webpage. i need to get over with this

Comment: Looks like the server doesn't send `404 Not Found` so you'll have to parse the contents - what contents are sent for file that "does not exist"?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `WebClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`:

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://someurl/doesnotexist.txt", "doesnotexist.txt");
```

This will throw a `System.Net.WebException` if the file does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you ought to test the ReponseCode.

You would expect a 200 "OK" code if the file exists and is transmitted to you, or a 404 "Not Found" code.

Try:

```
var response = clientx.GetResponse();
HttpStatusCode code = response.StatusCode;

if (code == HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    //get and download stream....
}
```

**EDIT:**

You need to cast the WebReponse into a HttpWebResponse (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx)

Try:

```
using(HttpWebReponse response = (HttpWebResponse)clientx.GetResponse())
{
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        string FilePath = @"C:\TextFiles\" + FileName + String.Format("{0:00000}", i) + ".TXT";
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(FilePath));

        using (FileStream download = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            Stream stream = clientx.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) !=0)
            {
                download.Write(buffer, 0, read);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```