# How to get original file name of a file from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have uploaded my file to my website with a random name. Now I want to get the original file name.

I have tried to get the file name:

```
var dllUrl = "https://cdn.example.com/c6244c971f.dll";
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(dllUrl);
Console.WriteLine(myFileVersionInfo.OriginalFilename);
```

but it did not work.

How can I get the original name from the version resource?

Comment: What do you mean with _orginal filename_? The name when the file was on the client machine? or just the _c6244c971f.dll_ part?

Comment: The parameter of [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo) is a file name, not a URL. So you need to download the file first and then call the method on the downloaded file.

Comment: @Steve The name when the file was on the client machine

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of [FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.getversioninfo) is a file name, not a URL.

You need to download the file (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238846/downloading-a-file-using-c-sharp)) to a temporary file and then use `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(temporaryFile)`.

There is no other was to do this, because the original file name is not encoded in the URL nor is there a HTTP verb (or any other standardized way) to get only the version resource of a file.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Klaus Gütter. You need to download the file.

Here is the code:

```
var uri = "https://cdn.example.com/c6244c971f.dll";
var uniqueFileName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
var uniqueFilePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\temp", uniqueFileName);

// Download the file
new WebClient().DownloadFile(uri, uniqueFilePath);

// Get file version info
FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(uniqueFilePath);
Console.WriteLine(myFileVersionInfo.OriginalFilename);

// Delete the file from local disk
File.Delete(uniqueFilePath);
```